# Package standard - "fetch" is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I´m using VSCode and the package *standar* in my node.js project to formatter my application.

```
$ npm i standard --save-dev
```

In my code, I'm doing a simple HTTP Request to some end point:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
```

The code works fine to me, but the standar show me the error ***fetch* is not defined**

I'm not sure why standard is showing me this message in *problems* window and in my .js file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem evidenced by standard Package, putting *window* in front the fetch

this:
`fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')`

to this:
`window.fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')`

This solves to me.

Comment: I have the same issue. After this change, I got `window is not defined` instead. Were you not seeing this issue?