# vscode extension API - "fetch is not defined"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, fetch-api, vscode-extensions, node-fetch

I recently picked up a VSCode extension project I've done about a year ago.

In code it uses `fetch` to call APIs

[image]

This `fetch` used to work if I hit Start Debugging on this extension project, but now it doesn't.

Everytime it gets to this line, VSCode would complain `fetch is not defined`

[image]

There was literally zero change.

I did look at [Package standard - "fetch" is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422533/package-standard-fetch-is-not-defined) but changing to `window.fetch` would give `window is not defined`.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `const fetch = require('node-fetch');`, install `node-fetch` with `npm`

Comment: global `fetch` is supported as of node 18.0.0.  See https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental Were you using the experimental fetch flag before.

Comment: And very likely you need to use `node-fetch` 2.x, https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/190.1.4/package.json#L17

Comment: Yeah, both node-fetch and axios work. It's just weird I didn't have to install any of these.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code extensions run in node.js and not in the browser context so `window.fetch` is not available.

As of today VS Code ships with node.js 16.x, which does not have support for `fetch` yet. `fetch` should be supported natively as soon as VS Code updates its node.js version to any version >= 18.x.

Until then consider using the `node-fetch@2` npm module.

Comment: our vscode extension has a dependency using `fetch`. It works fine on my system but fail's on my colleagues. Why could the difference be?

https://github.com/google/generative-ai-js/issues/6#issuecomment-1871806034

Comment: we figured this issue. on more inspection we found that colleague had vscode version 1.81 which used NodeJS v16.

Answer (score -2):

make the code block a separate function and then try again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).